# How can I get text (String) from ItemField

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am new to the `smart gwt` framework. My problem is, when I am working with ItemFields, there is no way how to get text from that particlar itemField. My goal is to fill the `firstName` `ItemField`, grab the text, and send it to the service, that I implemented.

How can I get string from that ItemField?
How is that, that there is no getText Method?

for example

```
final TextItem firstName = new TextItem("firstName", "First name");
*******************************************************************

public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    String name = firstName.????????;
    contactForm.greetings(name, new CallbackHandler());
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried [`getEnteredValue()`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html#getEnteredValue()) or [`getValue`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#getValue())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
getValueAsString()
  Return the value tracked by this form item.
```

So the code would be:

```
String name = firstName.getValueAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Doc](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html#getEnteredValue%28%29) you can use following code:

```
String name = firstName.getEnteredValue()
```